# css лишняя прокрутка по горизонтали. Как убрать

Tags: html, css

```css
h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

h2 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.button-read {
  color: #ddd;
  background: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 5px solid #ddd;
  transition: 1s;
}

.button-read:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  transition: 1s;
}

.last-bublication {
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container last-publication">
  <div class="raw">
    <h1>Latest News</h1>
    <h2>Description to last publication</h2>
    <button class="button-read">Прочитать</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Появляется горизонтальная прокрутка, когда добавляю к родительскому `last-publication` свойство `padding-bottom`.
Почему это происходит?
С `padding-top` все нормально.
Также она появляется, если у `button` `margin-bottom: 100px;`
Как исправить это и почему появляется?
Только без костыля `overflow-x`, пожалуйста.

Comment: прокрутка у всего окна появляется, а не у отдельного блока

Comment: если убрать 1 из эл-ов: button || h1 || h2, то пропадает прокрутка...

Comment: А родительский к <div class="container last-publication"> можно увидеть? Так как при назначении данных свойств, блок должен удлиняться

Comment: он в body находится.

Comment: я заметил, что прокрутка по горизонту начинается, когда контент в высоту становится больше чем окно

Comment: Я решил проблему, у меня хедер имел ширину 100vw; убрал и горизонтальная прокрутка исчезла, но почему vw так делает - непонятно

Answer (score 0):

Без полного исходного когда могу посоветовать лишь:

```
body {
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Цитата: "Только без костыля overflow-x"

Comment: @vp_arth  я умею читать. Какой пример кода, такой и ответ.

Comment: комменты к статье прочитайте, я же объяснил решение проблемы, осталось выяснить суть сего